# How to connect my ChromaDB collection and using langchain

Tags: vector, openai-api, embedding, langchain, chromadb

I just have a question for connect ChromaDB with langchain

Already tested chromadb and langchain using from_documents

But using Chroma.from_documents function that is always an embedding cost, right?

So I'm Already have embedding data So

When I receive request then make a collection and want to return result

```
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.chains import VectorDBQA
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain

import chromadb


chroma_client = chromadb.Client()
collection = chroma_client.create_collection(name = "Testing")
idx = [str(i) for i in range(len(embedded_df))]
documents = list(embedded_df['title'].values)
metadatas = embedded_df[['text']].to_dict(orient='record')
embedding_list = list(embedded_df['text_embedding'].values)
collection.add(
    documents = documents,
    embeddings = embedding_list,
    metadatas = metadatas,
    ids = idx
)
embedding_func = OpenAIEmbeddings(model='text-embedding-ada-002', query_model_name = 'text-embedding-ada-002')
langchainChroma = Chroma(client = chroma_client, collection_name = 'Testing', embedding_function=embedding_func)
llm = ChatOpenAI()
retriver = langchainChroma.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k":2})
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm = llm, chain_type='stuff', retriever = retriver)
query = """What is your most favorite food?"""
result = qa.run(query)
print(result)
```

But this code cannot return my data Just return chatgpt response

How to connect my ChromaDB collection and using langchain

Comment: as far  as I understood, since `from_documents` costs you, you want to communicate with chroma through chroma client and you are having issue. is this correct

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found away to tap in to the db and look through the documents .

refer to the documentation https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/chroma

on your code, something like the below may help.

```
db_records = langchainChroma.get()
print(db_records['documents']) # you may want to change the key as needed.
```